# How to evaluate a string as expression with a window object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, dom, window, eval

At the moment I'm trying to build something like Vue.js and Angular use :
v-if or ng-if. The problem is that I can't see how they did the expressions and evaluate them.

Atm I have something like :

```
<div r-if='window.store.value > 0'></div>
```

The thing is that it always returns false as it doesn't seem to parse the expression correctly.

I used the following code snippets to evaluate it ( element is the acquired DOM element ):

```
eval(element.getAttribute('r-if'))

var func = new Function("return " + element.getAttribute('r-if'));
return func();
```

Has anyone got a idea to approach this?

Comment: I've deleted my answer since I didn't get the question, so the answer was not relevant. Now I got your question, I have nothing useful to say except "Good luck to create a JavaScript framework!"

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

```
  if (window.eval(attribute)) {
          node.style.display = ""
  }
  else {
         node.style.display = "none"
  }
```

In the HTML it will look like this :

```
<span class="loader" r-if="window.store.isLoading()"></span>
```

It now can use your own 'global variables' in the window. Although window.store.variable didn't seem to work. Functions or mutations like a custom state management seemed to do the trick